# RSA - How can the client (in server context) encrypt/decrypt incoming data?

Tags: java, client-server, rsa

I have trouble understanding exactly how RSA works. Many examples and definitions attempt to explain but use a vague context.

So here is what I want to do:

I have a server that uses RSA and has a private and public key. From what I understand, upon connection the server sends the public key to the server in an unencrypted manner.. some kind of handshake if you will.

Further traffic would then occur in an encrypted fashion. To establish this fashion how would I be able to both encrypt what the client sends, and decrypt what the client receives (from client-sided perspective).

On server side encrypted data gets decrypted by the private key but I can't decrypt data in the client without that private key... that I can't have in the client because it's secret.

This confuses me, am I missing something obvious or is there need of a second private key?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As you have already pointed out is *RSA* an asymmetric encryption scheme, that means:

```
c = E(pub_key, m) // ciphertext = encryption(public key,  message)
m = D(pri_key, c) // message    = decryption(private key, ciphertext)
```

In contrast a symmetric encryption scheme (such as fore example *AES*) works the following:

```
c = E(key, m)
m = E(key, c)
```

In other words the same key is used for encryption and decryption.

And that is where the asymmetric cryptosystem comes into play. It allows to parties to securely exchange a secret key for symmetric encryption.

---

So basically how a primitive (but very vulnerable!) key exchange could look:

1. server sends to client his public key `pub_key_S`

   client sends to server his public key encrypted with the server's public key 
   `c = E(pub_key_S, pub_key_C)`

   server decrypts `c` with his private key `pub_key_C = D(pri_key_S, c)`

   server generates a new random symmetric secret key `key_CS`

   server encrypts the newly generated key with the client's public key `c = E(pub_key_C, key_CS)`

   server sends `c` to the client

   client decrypts ciphertext with his private key `pri_key_C` `key_CS = D(pri_key_C, c)`

Now Client and Server have a shared secret key `key_CS` which they can use to securely communicate for the ongoing session.

---

Such a protocol is in practice quite a bit more complicated, including certificates, digital signatures, hashcodes and so on. The probably most widely used protocol is [SSL or TLS](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security). (for in example *https*).

I recommend you to check out that link if you are interested in the details of such a protocol.

Comment: In your example the first one says the client sends the public key to the server, is it not the other way around? Though this is quite helpful in understanding it. Once the client received the symmetric key wont the encryption be useless because the key is there to grab?

Comment: I omitted a step. Usually the server sends his key first. Then the client sends his key encrypted with the server's public key. The symmetric key is only known to client and server. (since it has been send encrypted no eavesdropper can have any information about)

Comment: I see... So in a way, RSA would be a bit like the server giving a sealed box to the client where the client can put in his key (I don't know what key that is but I assume that this key would be a symmetric key) to seal it back up and give it back to the server?

Comment: Kind of, usually the server distributes the secret key. The server sending the public key to the client is mostly required for verifying the server's certificate/identity.

Comment: Alright so let me get this straight, upon connection the server sends a symmetric secret key to the client, but the server cannot encrypt this secret key because the client has no way of decrypting it until it has this symmetric key?

Comment: No, the server sends his Public Key. Then the client can verify it's certificate and afterwards send it's own public key to the server. (I have updated my answer with the first 2 steps)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58436/discussion-between-limnic-and-i-turo).

Answer (score 0):

First read [this article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_%28cryptosystem%29). Then you should know that usually asymmetric algorithms using for exchanging passwords and electronic signs. So the best way in client-server encryption is to generate common encryption key (with RSA or [Diffie–Hellman key exchange](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diffie_hellman)), and then use any of symmetric algo (AES for example) to encode data between server and client.

Comment: I see, so RSA is in fact not suited for common data exchange where both parties must be able to encrypt/decrypt but RSA is more like a one-way data transfer to like you said securely send passwords?

Comment: Correct, RSA is much more expensive in meaning of CPU time and encrypted data size, so usually its using only for initiating connection (and/or digital signing).